# An exception occurred processing JSP page /verifyUser.jsp at line 45

Tags: mysql, eclipse

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>
        Verify User
        </title>

    </head>

    <body>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("userID");
    String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
    //Step1: JDBC Driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //Step2: Define Connection URL
    String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/assignment?user=root&password=root";
    //Step3: Establish connection to URL
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
    String sql = "select * from login where UserId=? and Password=?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,userid);
    pstmt.setString(2,password);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){  
        session.invalidate();
        session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("LOGIN-STATUS", "YES");
        session.setAttribute("name",userid);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
        else{
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
    conn.close();
    }
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I intend to do is to create a login page. So, when I successfully login with the correct username and password, It brings me to another page. However Im facing a problem now where I login with the correct username and password, this error occurs. How do I fix this ?

Comment: There's no error message here. If you mean an exception occurred, you haven't shown what that exception was.

Comment: This is my jsp file which has an exception occurred.

Comment: *What* exception occurred? What message did it contain?